# Laravel lowers the quality of the image by uploading amazon s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm uploading images from the right to amazon s3, and when uploading the image loses quality.
The images I want to save directly in my amazon s3 bucket, to optimize the disk space of my virtual machine
I attach the source code.

```
public static function uploadToAmazon($photos, $ad_id)
{

    // Start Uploading to Amazon Cloud
    try {

        // Set loop couter
        $counter = 0;

        // Count photos
        $count_photos      = count($photos);

        // Manage each image
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {

            $preview_name   = 'preview_'   . $counter . '.jpg';
            $thumbnail_name = 'thumbnail_' . $counter . '.jpg';

            $image = Image::make($photo->getRealPath());

            // Get Ration
            $ratio        = $image->width() / $image->height();

            /**
            * Upload first thumbnails
            */
            $targetThumbWidth  = 270 * $ratio;
            $targetThumbHeight = $targetThumbWidth / $ratio;

            // Resize Thumbnail
            $thumbNewSize      = $image->fit($targetThumbWidth, $targetThumbHeight)->stream();

            Storage::disk('s3')->put('photos/'.$ad_id.'/thumbnails/'.$thumbnail_name, $thumbNewSize->__toString());
            Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility('photos/'.$ad_id.'/thumbnails/'.$thumbnail_name, 'public');

            /**
            * Now upload Preview images
            */
            $resposniveSize = Uploader::resposniveSize($image->width(), $image->height());

            // Resize Thumbnail
            $previewNewSize      = $image->fit($resposniveSize[0], $resposniveSize[1])->stream();

            // Check if Watermark enabled or not
            $is_watermark   = Uploader::is_watermark();

            if ($is_watermark) {

                // Get Watermark Options
                $watermark = $is_watermark['watermark'];
                $position  = $is_watermark['position'];

                // Insert Watermark
                $image->insert($watermark, $position);

            }

            Storage::disk('s3')->put('photos/'.$ad_id.'/previews/'.$preview_name, $previewNewSize->__toString());
            Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility('photos/'.$ad_id.'/previews/'.$preview_name, 'public');

            // New Counter
            $counter ++;

        }

        if($counter == $count_photos){

            // Return Previews Array
            $previews_array   = array();

            // Return Thumbnails Array
            $thumbnails_array = array();

            for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $count_photos - 1 ; $i++) { 

                array_push($previews_array, '/'.$ad_id.'/previews/preview_'.$i.'.jpg');
                array_push($thumbnails_array, '/'.$ad_id.'/thumbnails/thumbnail_'.$i.'.jpg');

            }

            // Return Data
            $data  = array(
                'previews_array'   => $previews_array, 
                'thumbnails_array' => $thumbnails_array, 
            );

            return $data;

        }else{

            return false;

        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        /*echo $e->getMessage();
        die();*/
        return false;

    }

}
```

The truth that I can not find the moment in which the image loses quality, will be to resize?

This is the original picture
[image]

This is the image that is in amazon s3
[image]

```
public static function resposniveSize($originalWidth, $originalHeight)
{
    // Get Ration
    $ratio        = $originalWidth / $originalHeight;

    // New Width
    $targetWidth  = intval(500 * $ratio);

    // New Height
    $targetHeight = intval($targetWidth / $ratio);

    return array($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
}
```

Comment: What does the function `Uploader::resposniveSize` do?

Comment: I added the function that you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having here is that you resize the Image to thumbnail size first. After which you scale it up to your preview size. This results in a loss of quality.

So instead of using:

`$thumbNewSize      = $image->fit($targetThumbWidth, $targetThumbHeight)->stream();`

Try to use this:

```
$thumbNewSize = $image;
$thumbNewSize->fit($targetThumbWidth, $targetThumbHeight)->stream();
```

Same goes for `$previewNewSize`.

You could also try to use `->resize($targetThumbWidth, $targetThumbHeight)` instead of `->fit()`

Comment: I have applied the change you suggested to me, and I have obtained the same results, the image continues to lose quality.

Comment: You could try to use ->resize($targetThumbWidth, $targetThumbHeight) instead of ->fit()

Comment: I've tried, without any success, I do not find the error or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed the order in which it was executed and it has worked.
For some reason, however much I put in different variables, I tried to enlarge the image that was first reduced, so that the quality dropped.